What motivated Paul to put his ring in his pocket in this scene?
After Stilgar gives him the name Muad'Dib Usul, Paul sits alone in the desert,
feeling the ring on his finger:

Paul: Father, I found my way.

Then Paul takes out the ring and puts it in his pocket, and Chani joins him:

Paul: It's breathtaking.

What motivated Paul to put his ring in his pocket in this scene?

–1 This question shows no effort to understand or research an answer.

In the book, Paul receives the names Usul and Paul-Muad'Dib just after he killed Jamis in single combat.  Jamis had challenged whether Jessica and Paul could be admitted to the tribe, and Paul's victory showed they could.  It was fitting for Paul to receive his Fremen names at that time.  This was Chapter 33.  The book does not have the scene you ask about, where Paul is alone in the desert and removes the ducal signet ring from his finger.
However, there is a scene two years later that may provide an explanation for not wearing the ring in the movie as well as in the book.  In Chapter 44 most of the Fremen have gathered together, and Paul speaks to the assembled tribes to convince them that he should not kill off their leaders in the traditional way of becoming the leader of all Fremen.  During his speech, Paul shows them the signet ring:

From his neck he [Paul] took a braided shigawire cord and removed a ring from the cord, holding the ring aloft. "This was my father's ducal signet," he said.  "I swore never to wear it again until I was ready to lead my troops over all of Arrakis and claim it as my rightful fief." He put the ring on his finger, clenched his fist.

Paul was not ready to lead the Fremen over all of Arrakis just after he received his tribal names, so he didn't wear the ring.  (in the book he wasn't wearing it yet; in the movie he took it off). He put the ring on two years later when he was ready.
